# Uncheck a checkbox in webpage through WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to uncheck/check a checkbox within a webpage that is loaded within a webbrowser control?  Thank you.

Update:  (This is what I originally tried with no luck)

```
HtmlDocument rememberme = this.webBrowser1.Document;
rememberme.GetElementById("remBox").SetAttribute("checked", "false");
```

Comment: The CHECKED attribute is not actually a bool, but a present or not present, which is probably why SetAttribute("checked", "false") failed.  You might be able to just remove the attribute entirely.

Comment: You can just set it null and it should work:  ele.SetAttribute("checked", null);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

`webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript`

see:

[InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx)

This way you can call JS function that will do what you want to the page.

Another way is to use mshtml API, like this:
`( ( HTMLInputElement )this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById( "test" ).DomElement ).@checked = false;`

Comment: What would be a proper way to use JavaScript to uncheck a single checkbox?

Comment: It depends - if you know checkbox's ID, then just use 
`document.getElementById( 'yourid' ).checked = false;`
But if it is dynamic (like in ASP.NET in control) than you would have to use another way - locate it by class name, traverse DOM tree or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the InvokeMember Method of a HTML Element to invoke a DOM Event. In our case "click". If you have a WebBrowser Control than all you have to do is find the element and Invoke the Method.

```
For Each ele As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If ele.Name = "accept" Then
            ele.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
Next
```

In my example 'accept' was the name of the checkbox element. You can use the SetAttribute() for some other controls but the best way to emulate a click is to find what the checkbox state is by using GetAttribute() and click if the checkbox is set to false. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you should be able to use the clientId to set .checked = false.

Comment: What does that have to do with the webbrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript.aspx
you need to analyze the page structure to find out how to locate the checkbox and use Myles's method to check/uncheck the checkbox in javascript.

Comment: It would be more complicated if you skip .Net's wrapper classes and call IE API directly.

Comment: My point is that once you've got the document in the webbrowser control you can manipulate the dom objects directly, without resorting to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The LONG version is that you'll have to use DOM functions to find the client ID of the control you want to update, then just set it's value.

I can probably find some sample code for you once I get to work if no one else beats me to it...

EDIT:

Basically all you need to do is:

```
HTMLDocumentClass doc = webBrowserControl.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;

HTMLInputElement input = doc.all.item("checkboxID", 0) as HTMLInputElement;

input.value ="false";  //Could be 0, not sure... 
//could also be input.@checked = false, sorry I haven't actually used this on a checkbox before... one of these should work though
```

So yeah, not sure why anyone would go through all the effort to write a JavaScript and invoke it when you can set a control's value with 3 lines of code.

Comment: It should be `input.@checked = false;`. 
And using JS you don't have to reference mshtml and you can do this in one line - `this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript( "uncheck" );`.

Comment: Well, one line in C# + one in JS.

Comment: Well I _could_ condense it down to one line of C# if I really wanted to. ;)  I suspect actually adding the script to the page and using it would end up being more.

Comment: Solution with mshtml in my answer actually is one line ;) And JS approach to be one line would require access to the page source - otherwise it would be necessary to use mshtml API to insert your script.